# DataGridView not showing all columns in data set

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I have a simple Dataset viewer app that shows the contents of a dataset.  My dataset has many datatables each with many rows.  Unfortunately one of the tables is only showing the first column.  When I look at the datatable in the debugger I see all the rows, when it's displayed in the datagridview only the one row. There doesn't seem to be anything weird about the column names.

Here's the code that sets the datagridview:

```
    ' Load datagrid
    With DataGridViewXml
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = ssrsReportDataSet
        .DataMember = ssrsReportDataSet.Tables(0).TableName
    End With
```

' Table at index 4 is the one losing the columns
        tableSelecter.SelectedIndex = 4

Here's how I update the view with the table I need:

```
' Load datagrid
With DataGridViewXml

    .DataMember = ssrsReportDataSet.Tables("MyTable").TableName
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `DataMember` at all, why not do this:

```
DataGridViewXml.DataSource = ssrsReportDataSet.Tables(0)
```

and then this:

```
DataGridViewXml.DataSource = ssrsReportDataSet.Tables("MyTable")
```

There's no point setting `AutoGenerateColumns` because it's `True` by default.  You may or may not need to set the `DataSource` to `Nothing` and `Clear` the `Columns` collection in between.

Comment: I removed the DataMember settings. I guess they would save some time with very large datasets, but don't seem to make a difference here. I now clear the datasource and columns. This one table still doesn't get all it's columns though. Kinda frustrating to see it in the debugger and not have it load correctly in the datagridview. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the length or name of the table and column.

Comment: One of my coworkers just mentioned that autogenerate columns may not work if the columns have some nulls. So I can either manually generate them or replace nulls with a single white space. Neither are great options. I'll keep digging around, thanks.

Comment: That does seem very strange.  I wouldn't have thought that the data in the columns would make any difference to whether they get added to the grid or not.  What gets added to the grid is based on `PropertyDescriptors` generated by the `DataTable's` `DefaultView`.